# Map does not zoom when feature is selected on Feature Table

Tags: arcgis-js-api

According to the API [Feature Table API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featuretable-amd.html#syncselection) both the `syncSelection` and the `zoomToSelection` properties are true by default so I thought that meant when I selected a row the map would zoom in on the selected feature but that doesn't appear to be true.  In the sample at [Feature Table Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=featuretable_custommenu) the map centers on the selected feature but the zoom level does not change.  Is there a way to make the map zoom in on the selected feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it zoom using dojo's `aspect`. It will make all calls to `map.centerAt` in your application do the zoom too, but is maybe your best option in this case, assuming the application is simple. Something like this:

```
    aspect.after(map, "centerAt", function(target, m) {
     map.centerAndZoom(m[0], 16);
     return target;
    }.bind(this));
```

Don't forget to include `dojo/aspect` in your AMD includes.

Comment: If I understand your example the zoom level would always be 16.  Is there a way to make the zoom level depend on the selected feature's extent?

Comment: Sure, if you have polygons you can use the call the [getExtent function](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/polygon-amd.html#getextent) on the Polygon to get that, and then pass that to `centerAndZoom`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Gavin's answer works but I wound up using the code in the `ZoomToSelectedFeature's` menu option in [Feature Table Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=featuretable_custommenu) as follows.  (The `ROUTE_ID` was an attribute of the selected feature).

```
myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){
    zoomToRoute(evt[0].data.ROUTE_ID);
    });

function zoomToRoute(routeId){
  var query = new Query();
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = [ "*" ];
  query.where = "ROUTE_ID = '" + routeId + "'" ;
  routeFeature.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(features){
        var extent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(features).expand(1.25); 
        map.setExtent(extent);
    });
}
```